# Creating a new variable in R from two existing ones

Tags: r

My apologies if this is a basic question. I'm new to R.

I have a dataset, DAT, which has 3 variables: ID, V1 and V2. Unfortunately, V2 data are missing for many cases. I want to create a new variable, V3. I want V3 to have the same values as V2, but for any case that has a missing value for V2, I want V3 to take the value of V1 instead. What is the most efficient way to do this in R?

Comment: You can do this with indexing: `DAT$V3 = DAT$V2; DAT$V3[is.na(DAT$V2)] = DAT$V1[is.na(DAT$V2)]`. `is.na(DAT$V2)` returns `TRUE` for rows with missing data for `V2`. So you use this to select the rows to replace with the values in `V1`.

Comment: another option is `coalesce` from the `dplyr` package: `dat$V3 = coalesce(dat$V2, dat$V1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the ifelse statement.

DAT$V3 <- ifelse(is.na(DAT$V2), DAT$V1, DAT$V2)

Reads as if V2 is blank then use V1, otherwise use the data in V2.

Answer (score 1):

One approach using the `dplyr` package.

```
# Step 1: Load verb-like data wrangling package. 
library(dplyr)

# Step 2: Create some data.
df <- data.frame(ID=1:5, V1 = 11:15, V2 = c(31:33, NA, NA))
```

> ```
> ID  V1 V2
>   1 11 31
>   2 12 32
>   3 13 33
>   4 14 NA
>   5 15 NA
> ```

```
# Step 3: Create a variable V3 using your criteria
df <- mutate(df, V3 = if_else(is.na(V2), V1, V2))
```

> ```
> ID  V1 V2 V3
>   1 11 31 31
>   2 12 32 32
>   3 13 33 33
>   4 14 NA 14
>   5 15 NA 15
> ```

Using the data.table package would probably be more efficient if you have a big data frame.

Comment: Thank you! The ifelse statement was key here.